# Apache Tomcat/7.0.11 Can't acces to Host Manager

Tags: apache, tomcat

> I installed Apache Tomcat/7.0.11 to work Java EE project, i configured
>   many things...but when i want to get acces to my Host Manager page, **I
>   CAN'T**. but i can get acces to Manager App and Server Status
>
> my tomcat-user.xml file look like :

```
<user name="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="admin-gui,standard,manager-gui"/>

Can someone help me to resolve this problem?
```

Comment: what error do you get when you try to access the host manager page? 403?

Comment: it's a 403 Access Denied

Comment: Your version is very old and unsecure. You should upgrade to 7.0.40 first.

Comment: i just download it few days ago !!

Comment: @archavin, then you did something wrong: https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

Comment: @Micheal-O thanks, but there si any good tutorial to setup tomcat for eclipse helios ? i found a lot but no one give detailed information.